# text-align center for opera - css

Tags: css, opera

if Chrome is look like this:

```
.text-center {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}
```

and firefox:

```
.text-center {
  text-align: -moz-center;
}
```

how about in opera?

```
.text-center {
  text-align: -o-center;
}
```

is not working.

**UPDATE:**

HTML:

```
  .container
    .text-center.label-margin
      %h3
        .bubble LEADERSHIP
```

CSS of my bubble class.

```
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 11px 0 0 0 !important;
  background-color: #333333 !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

it looks like in OPera[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to prefix the text-align property. You can simply use:

```
text-align:center;
```

instead (which should work on all browsers).

**Further Reading:**

- [W3.org documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-align) on the text-align property.
- Here's quite a nice [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/) article that you might find useful.
- If we're talking about any property, [caniuse...](http://caniuse.com/) is one of the 'best' browser compatibility websites out there, with info on nearly all css properties.

---

Please also note: Border-radius does not require prefixing (and hasn't done for quite some time now), whilst using `!important` is considered bad practise, so I would personally advise to get out of the habit of using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/up0Lo9vx/1/)**

```
.center{
text-align-center;   
}
```

No need to use specifically for all the browsers,as its almost accepted by all browser